Extracting Audio
I'm trying to extract this audio from a 1998 game called Brain Shift.
Back in 2016, I discovered a way to be able to listen to the sounds indvidually like an A-Z mode but there's static in the audio. See sample below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MTvvaE7ku9QGYf7xOTXednOG9x9DVFOq/view?usp=sharing
I discovered recently that it's possible to dump a MASK ROM by taking photographs of the logic board. An engineer recently bought a Brain Shift and got me a scan of the games logic board. Another engineer said that the rectangle is the ROM area:

I wonder what can be done to get a ROM dump of this game. The CPU may be a 6502-like chip with the sound chip may be from SunPlus.

You should have included pictures and more info on the board itself, so that we can see possible routes and ways to get the audio.

First, let's clarify the terminology:

logic board: the circuit board assembly (PCB) with ICs (chips) and other electronic components on it

chip/IC: a silicon die packaged in a plastic or ceramic package, with a metal leadframe that ends up in "pins" that connect the chip to the PCB; Connection between the leadframe and the die is done using very thin wires

silicon die: a chunk of silicon wafer with patterns that make it  do a particular function. The photo you show is that of a die, not of a "chip" or a "logic board".



I discovered a way to be able to listen to the sounds indvidually like an A-Z mode

Great work! That's a diagnostic mode used to verify that the SFX hardware works. Mask ROMs tend to go bad over time, unfortunately - it's called "bit rot" and it's due to fairly poor manfacturing process control back when they were made. So, the sequential ("A-Z") mode is there to "listen through" the ROM contents to confirm they are good.
Modern mask ROMs last essentially forever.

there's static in the audio

Does the audio have static in it when the game is being normally played? It may be that the static is always there but is just obscured by the sound track. The audio in the ROMs is likely encoded in some way that reduces its fidelity and the number of bytes needed to store it. Chip die area has to be conserved to keep the costs down. So it was always advantageous to find ways to store audio without using as much data as an unprocessed, full-resolution "WAV" recording would take.
You'd probably want to capture the audio directly from the sound chip's output using a good external sound "card", and to record it as a raw WAV file, without any compression. You'd also want to disconnect any active loads to the sound chip output, like mixer stages etc., since they may be injecting noise back into the sound chip output.
Some reverse engineering of the audio output circuit (not ICs/dies) is necessary to figure it out.
With a high-resolution direct capture, the digital values of the DAC output could be reproduced exactly, and further processing done on them to clean up the audio. In essence, a modern 24-bit audio input device is so good that it can see the "jaggies" or "steps" in the output of the audio DACs used in those games. Thus, the digital data fed to the DAC can be extracted exactly, with no errors due to the analog path.

it's possible to dump a MASK ROM by taking photographs of the logic board

No. It's possible by taking photographs of the die inside the ROM chip itself, or of the ROM area inside the sound chip die (if that's where the sound ROM is). The board the chip is on is in the way pretty much and is of no use other than a carrier of the chip, and the die inside. The chip has to be de-capped, which is a potentially destructive process, to expose the die. Then the die can be photographed.

An engineer recently bought a Brain Shift and got me a scan of the games logic board.

What you show us is a partial picture of a particular die, not a "scan of the logic board". The logic board is huge. What you see on the picture is just a few mm across in size, and is (was) buried inside one of the chips on that board.

Another engineer said that the rectangle is the ROM area

"The" rectangle? I'm far from an expert, but here are my guesses at what's visible on the partial die photo you provided:


(light blue) There are several "PADs" where bonding wires can attach.

(red) "X" look like large transistors/mosfets

(dark blue) It's an area of logic, looks way too irregular to be a part of a ROM.


I'm quite certain there are no ROMs visible anywhere on the photo - not unless most of their structure was buried deep under the metal and completely invisible. That's unlikely.
Someone better-versed in chip design will probably pitch in and correct me :)

If the sound ROM(s) are external to the sound chip, then there is no chip need to decap the chips and reverse engineer their silicon dies. The ROMs chip can be removed from the logic board, and read out using nothing much - an Arduino UNO is often enough, or a Mega with 3.3V-to-5V level converters.

I can get the device to play random numbers through a test mode when it is on low batteries, I haven't been able to reduce the static, the audio quality that the number rapidifre plays is much higher than this, this is one example: https://youtube.com/shorts/IogN07gPNgc?si=pYlFEZQoMtnfdzMY

@Samlaptop Mob Shift is a remake of this for smartphones. Hopefully it has nicer sounds in it. My mistake was that I thought you were dealing with an arcade cabinet, not a small board game device. I might be able to buy one and have a look, if I can find it locally.

Yeah I'm making a new version of it with a new name and I'm trying to get the voice files from the original game so that my new actor will be able do a much better redo of the voice! I still can't believe how a modified Brain Shift was able to play all the sounds from the chip. They're on eBay and Mercari in the US!

Without knowing more about the PCB, it is hard to give you a more precise answer.
Right now, all I can tell you is that it sounds like an 8-bit audio which has not been dithered and "noise-shaped", and that the noise you are hearing is the quantization noise.
It is possible that you have somehow tapped into the audio which was not yet processed completely, maybe not even (completely) converted from digital to analog.
